# Docker: Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed

Tags: java, docker

(Please note that the command was working before few days)

I have a docker image that uses ubuntu:18.04, and I installed java8 on it. When I tried to build a Docker image, I have the following error:

```
No /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/wgetrc file found.
Creating /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/wgetrc and
using default oracle-java8-installer wgetrc settings for it.
Downloading Oracle Java 8...
--2019-01-16 22:46:54--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u191-b12/2787e4a523244c269598db4e85c51e0c/jdk-8u191-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 2.17.26.151
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|2.17.26.151|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u191-b12/2787e4a523244c269598db4e85c51e0c/jdk-8u191-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
--2019-01-16 22:46:54--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u191-b12/2787e4a523244c269598db4e85c51e0c/jdk-8u191-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 104.87.3.121, 2a00:18d8:0:185::366, 2a00:18d8:0:184::366
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|104.87.3.121|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u191-b12/2787e4a523244c269598db4e85c51e0c/jdk-8u191-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1547678935_b60271d5afa954667df772f862d13890 [following]
--2019-01-16 22:46:56--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u191-b12/2787e4a523244c269598db4e85c51e0c/jdk-8u191-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1547678935_b60271d5afa954667df772f862d13890
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|2.17.26.151|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u191-b12/2787e4a523244c269598db4e85c51e0c/jdk-8u191-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1547678935_b60271d5afa954667df772f862d13890 [following]
--2019-01-16 22:46:56--  https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u191-b12/2787e4a523244c269598db4e85c51e0c/jdk-8u191-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1547678935_b60271d5afa954667df772f862d13890
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|2.17.26.151|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2019-01-16 22:47:00 ERROR 404: Not Found.

download failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 installed oracle-java8-installer package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The command I used to download and install Java8 is:

```
# Java 1.8
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y && \
    apt-get update && \
    echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections && \
    apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer && \
    apt-get clean
```

Comment: It's the same for oracle-java8-installer - I updated the description to get-rid the confusion for the future readers. Thanks, @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas!

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use OpenJDK?

Comment: @makoto - AFAICT - It shows more stability than OpenJDK; especially, for production purposes.

Comment: That's largely a myth, unless you're using some specific Oracle-packaged binary which isn't supported on OpenJDK 8.  Going forward, OpenJDK is the same thing as Oracle JDK, just free.  You may want to get a bit more comfortable with using OpenJDK while you have the liberty to.

Comment: Can you maybe use the `java:8-jre` image?

Comment: It says "Download failed" and "404: Not found". Maybe a temporary network issue?

Comment: @makoto - We tried to replace the Oracle JDK w/ OpenJDK in the past, It required a lot of optimization regarding their GC and memory management (We don't know if they optimized OpenJDK nowadays - We will revisit it later), but the problem in the description stopped my progress for awhile. Probably, I will download the JDK on my machine or on a local repository on my network then I will add it to my Docker image during the build. The strange thing, the command has been stopped suddenly!

Comment: @kichik - I will try, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Thilo - TBH, I don't know. When I run the command today, it works! I feel your assumption is very close to the truth of the situation here.

Comment: Thank you all for all your great suggestions and the valuable question. I run the command again, and It works. Probably, it was a network issue as @Thilo assumption.